# Java classpath with and without colon ":"

Tags: java, macos, classpath

I'm learning Java and I have a quirk that I think only someone with experience can answer (I have been through the whole list of similar problems on SO).

When running from command line after compiling in Eclipse, this works

```
java -classpath : test.class
```

and this does not

```
java test.class
```

nor specifying the directory

```
java -classpath bin test.class
```

but specifying with a colon DOES

```
java -classpath bin: test.class
```

It was my understanding that

1. Java checked the current working directory by default
2. The colon was only used if you were specifying more than one path where I just have one.

Comment: You can't use : and .class extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to run "java test" not "java test.class"

Cheers

Comment: It's possible `test` is the package and `class` is the classname

Comment: In this case, the first command should not execute either.

Comment: Robert was correct. My actual class name is quite long so I hit the Tab key for it to autocomplete and thought nothing further of it.

Comment: It's not possible to have class as the class name, it's a reserved word AFAIK.